# EasyTracker.getTracker() returning NULL for Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

We have had code running live now for 9+ months with no issues but have started getting reports of the app crashing at random times (reports indicate it is only on Android 4.1 and 4.2, haven't been able to replicate it very well).  The code focuses around a widget that fetches a list of data (image urls and text) from an API of ours and displays this in a rotating widget on the desktop.  The widgets run the RemoteViewsService below that, on onDataSetChanged(), tracks what is being shown.

```
//// widget service
class WidgetRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService implements RemoteViewsFactory
{

... (other methods)

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged()
{
    ... (get data, do stuff)
    for ( Campaign campaign : campaigns )
    {
      GoogleAnalyticsTracker.trackEvent(getApplicationContext(), campaign.getGuid());
    }
}

}

//////// tracking code
protected static void trackEvent(Context context, String campaignGuid)
{
  EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();
  easyTracker.setContext(context);
  Tracker tracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();  // getTracker returns null
  if ( StringUtils.isNotBlank(campaignGuid) )
  {
    tracker.setCustomDimension(CAMPAIGN_GUID_DIMENSION_ID, campaignGuid);
  }
  ... (set other tracking data)
  tracker.trackEvent(category, action, label, null);    
  easyTracker.dispatch();
}
```

Our analytics.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-9999999-33</string>

<bool name="ga_debug">false</bool>
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">300</integer>

</resources>
```

When tracker.setCustomDimension() is called we get a NullPointerException (yeah, forgot to wrap that in a try/catch, so it crashes the widget and app).  In the log files we see:

```
11-14 13:08:37.651: W/GAV2(7863): Thread[Binder_2,5,main]: Connection to service failed 1
11-14 13:08:37.651: W/ActivityManager(259): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }: not found
11-14 13:08:37.691: W/GAV2(7863): Thread[Binder_2,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
11-14 13:08:37.691: E/AndroidRuntime(7863): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder_1
11-14 13:08:37.691: E/AndroidRuntime(7863): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 13:08:37.691: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at com.fake.tracking.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.trackEvent(GoogleAnalyticsTracker.java:58)
```

The error happens infrequently and at seemingly random times (when tablet is unlocked, opening/closing an app, etc.) and there are no other indications in the log that anything caused this.  We are running v2 of the Google Analytics JAR.

Comment: I also get random crash reports on Dev console, 1 in a couple of months, and oddly enough, these crashes aren't reported in Crashlytics and ofcourse, not in Google analytics. I get these: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(context) or startActivity(activity) before calling getTracker()`. Don't know what to do here.